# Convert utc time to system current time using ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, utc

How to convert UTC time to current system using ruby?

I'm using `Time.now.utc.iso8601` to get UTC format in ruby, I want to convert this to system current time using ruby.

Can someone help me with sample code?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you want to keep the time exactly as is, just change the timezone? If so this should get you where you need to go.  No need to convert it to `iso8601`, but if you already have it then just use `strptime` and ignore the `Z` on the end.

```
> now = Time.now
=> 2015-03-20 17:26:22 -0700
> now.utc
=> 2015-03-21 00:26:22 UTC
> now.utc.asctime
=> "Sat Mar 21 00:26:22 2015"
> Time.parse(now.utc.asctime)
=> 2015-03-21 00:26:22 -0700
```

Comment: yes..I want same UTC format with my local time zone. Can you tell how I can do that. I'm totally new to ruby so don't mistake if this question is immature one.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby Time class has a getlocal method:

`t = Time.now.utc
    => 2015-03-21 00:29:47 UTC
 t.getlocal
    => 2015-03-20 20:29:47 -0400`

See here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-c-local